# WinForms DatagridView allows deletion via Shift + Del keys even though AllowUserToDeleteRows property is set to false

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm using the standard .Net Winforms datagridview control to display & manipulate data, however I have (or thought so) suppressed user deletion via:

this.dataGridViewTestSteps.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

Now pressing 'Del' does in fact not delete rows, but surprisingly Pressing [Shift] and [Del] at the same time does. What's up with Shift-key overriding the property set above? Is there anything I can do to *fully* disallow deletion?

Comment: You'd be correct in assuming that your code should suppress all ability to delete. I tried to mimic your situation, but it would seem that holding Shift has no affect on my ability to block row deletion. Do you have any custom code that is attached to the grid for other purposes?

Comment: Could it be you stick to the Shift-Del shortcut somewhere to support cutting to the clipboard?

Comment: Thanks you two, however nothing in particular is blocking or allowing this from our code. The 'KeyDown'-event is in fact handled, but like this: private void dataGridViewTestSteps_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                removeSelectedRows();
            }
        }

Comment: apparently I am not the only one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2bf8f993-f523-494a-a4b4-4916b016cf76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my - the solution is apparently rather simple, but somewhat unexpected: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> seems to be a system wide alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. E.g. when editing a text in notepad.exe, selecting some characters and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> it seems to have the same effect & functionality as a standard Cut / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> would do.

Since I do handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> in my application, it does proceed and 'delete' these rows, even though they are actually placed on the clipboard.

So this has nothing to do in particular with the datagridview, usercode for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> is simply also called when <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> is pressed.